# SQL aggregation for identical values

Tags: sql

Suppose I have data something like this

| id | project-id | thing-count | country |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 4 | GBR |
| 2 | 1 | 2 | GBR |
| 3 | 1 | 8 | GBR |
| 4 | 2 | 1 | USA |
| 5 | 2 | 4 | USA |
| 6 | 2 | 9 | USA |

I want to group the data using the project-id and keep the country. I know that the country does not vary within a project. There seem to be two ways I can do this:

```sql
SELECT
  project-id,
  MIN(country) AS country
FROM data
GROUP BY project-id
```

or

```sql
SELECT
  project-id,
  country
FROM data
GROUP BY 
  project-id,
  country
```

These both work, but neither seem right. The first puts an extra burden on the `GROUP BY` since there's an unnecessary `MIN` calculation, while the second suggests to anyone reading the query that I want to `GROUP BY` the country data.

I'm always surprised that there is no `FIRST`, `LAST`, or `ANY` aggregation function, but as far as I can tell neither [SQL Server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/aggregate-functions-transact-sql), [MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/aggregate-functions.html), nor [Postgres](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/functions-aggregate.html) have that.

How can I write his query so that the `GROUP BY` does not need to do extra work aggregating a column whose entries are identical, in a way that makes it obvious in the SQL that I do not care which of the values being aggregated is chosen to represent the set of values?

Comment: In MySQL you can do `SELECT project-id, ANY_VALUE(country) as country, FROM data GROUP BY project-id`

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/why-should-i-tag-my-rdbms

Comment: Sample data is fine, but you should also _specify_ the expected result.

Comment: @jarlh I've added the results as requested but I think that makes the question _less_ readable since it suggests I am after a query that will obtain the results, but I already have two of them! Are you sure it helps the question?

Comment: @AmirSaleem that's just what I'm after. I guess I'm perplexed why (1) it is not available in other databases, and (2) why it is in the MySQL documentation under misc. functions not under aggregate functions.

Comment: The specified result says you want `SELECT DISTINCT`.

Comment: No, I don't. The question is about `GROUP BY`

Answer (score 1):

Two errors in my original question: `FIRST` and `LAST`. I need to constantly remind myself that SQL rows have no implicit ordering (think *sets* not *lists*) and so these aggregate functions would not make sense. But `ANY` does make sense, and I have expected it to be available time and time again.

In a comment on the question [@amir-saleem](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6289362/amir-saleem) points out that this does exist in MySQL. Using the [`ANY_VALUE` aggregation function](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/miscellaneous-functions.html#function_any-value) I could write

```sql
SELECT project-id, ANY_VALUE(country) as country, FROM data GROUP BY project-id
```

(N.B. `ANY_VALUE` looks like a useful aggregation function, but it is included in the [Miscellaneous Functions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/miscellaneous-functions.html) documentation rather than the [Aggregate Functions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/aggregate-functions.html) documentation; I do not know why.)

There is no similar aggregate function in Postgres as far as I can tell, though I could use a custom aggregate function to achieve this. Here are some community provided examples that would work in my case:

- [First/last (aggregate)](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/First/last_(aggregate))
- [Aggregate_Random](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Aggregate_Random)

(I have not investigated SQL Server based solutions.)

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding correctly, you basically want a list of all project IDs and their associated countries?

If so, you can do some by simply adding a distinct clause after select as shown below

```
Select distinct project-id,country from data
```

Comment: In this case yes, but I chose a deliberately simple example. I'd like a more general answer where the `GROUP BY` is important.